# How to keep both 32bit and 64bit RVM rubies

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, rvm

I am using 32bit and 64bit Ubuntus on different machines, and I have a single portable USB HDD which I keep my `/home` on. I have problems with locally installed RVM, as different architectures require different Rubies (and native gems too, I presume).

Is there a way that I can keep both versions of Ruby versions, and have RVM use whichever suits the currently running Ubuntu?

Comment: How do you get around the problems? I don't use Ruby so I don't know the details. Is there an env variable you export? Since the binaries will not be in your $HOME, what is it that is causing the problems?

Comment: Well, rvm install binaries in `/home` by default, in `.rvm` subdirectory. Then, every ruby has its own subdirectory there and, basically, the current active ruby is selected by changing the binary lookup path.

Answer (score 1):

you could use names like:

```
rvm install ruby-n64
```

or you could force 32 bit installation:

```
rvm install ruby --32
```